# What anchor type should I use for mounting a pull-up bar installation into concrete?

Tags: concrete, walls, safety, mounting, anchor

So yesterday I got a pull up bar at a really good price. Now the only thing I got to do is to mount it to a **solid concrete** wall. Since a nearby shop offers only a few different anchors, I bought two types that would fit best.

Sleeve anchor - 1/4'' (5/16'' drill) width x 4'' length,
Wedge anchor 5/16'' width x 2.5'' length

Pull up bar thickness is 4/5'' (2cm) and there are 8 holes

[image]

But here is the problem... I know that the sleeve anchors holding values are less in terms of shear and pullout than those of wedge type. On the other hand the wedge type anchors are really short and the pull up bar itself is thicker than the maximum value allowed for this length of the anchor.

The question is : Should I look for longer wedge type anchors? I live far from the city and would have to order some.

Or are the sleeve type anchors sufficient for the strain that's typical for a workout? Would also like to exercise using a TRX. (Not just me, flatmates too) so safety is a priority.

Comment: Can you confirm the wall is absolutely solid concrete?  Your pic is of tile.

Comment: How thick is the wall? Can you get to the other side? Could you put coach bolts through from the other side?

Comment: The floor at the picture is unrelated. Excuse me for the confusing pic. The destined wall is solid concrete for sure. The wall is at least 7''. But since it's the outer wall of my flat, I have no access to the other side.

Comment: Ok I'm pretty sure that the BIG concern is going to be shear strength, not length.

Comment: I suppose shear strength is related to width? I tried 3/8'' ones but they couldn't fit through the holes. That would solve the problem but unfortunately they are just a little bit too wide. You can see one at the picture, I can't pull it out. Since the wedge anchors are wider and generally have better shear strength, do you suggest buying longer wedge type than going with the current ones?

Comment: Is the actual grab bar missing from your picture? If what the picture shows is the wall bracket only, and the bar will sit out on the end of those square tube arms, there **will** be "pull out" forces; a lot, all along the top of the bracket. In fact, that is much more of a concern than shear strength. You should get longer wedge anchors so they are set to the proper depth or they could pull out.

Answer (score 1):

Tapcon makes a [heavy duty masonry screw](https://www.tapcon.com/products/concrete-screw-anchors/heavy-duty-tapcon) designed for applications like ledger boards. They come in the longer lengths as well. You'll have to drill holes with a masonry bit first (you can buy bits for a standard drill if you don't have a hammer drill), but they bite really well.

I have a pull-up bar mounted on wood studs (had to cleat it with 2x4s since the holes didn't line up). Just to be sure the cleat can't move I have 2 4" lag bolts driven in the top with 3" screws driven in the bottom. I would want a minimum of 3" on this to make sure it doesn't move.

Answer (score 0):

The wedge anchors you've shown are fairly standard. I'd go that route. Sleeve anchors of the type you have here are more for hollow wall applications, I think. They need room to expand sufficiently.

Anyway, if you install the wedge anchors to adequate depth they should work well. I'd want the gripping portion inserted at least an inch to reduce the chance of surface blowout. The deeper you go the wider the force is distributed in the concrete. You may need to find some longer ones.

I would install six anchors, forgoing one at each top corner. Drilling holes in concrete that close together often results in collapse. Six should be plenty (with four being at the top).